# How to get TableCell node of row selected

Tags: javafx, tableview

I have the following code that I use whenever a user selects a row. Is there any way you can grab the first or the selected cell from the selected row? I need the selected cell because I want the pass that node to the `ControlsFX POPOVER.show()` method. I need the `popover box` to appear right over the selected row in the `tableview`.

```java
tableView.setRowFactory(tv -> {
    TableRow<ObservableList> row = new TableRow<>();
    row.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
        if (event.getClickCount() == 2 && (!row.isEmpty())) {
            popover.show(cellNodeHere<-);
        }
    });

    return row;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your last question just change the row factory to this.  You can use [`getCellData`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumnBase.html#getCellData-int-).

```java
Label label = new Label("click a row");
tableView.setRowFactory(tv -> {
   TableRow<ObservableList> row = new TableRow<>();    
   row.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
       if (event.getClickCount() == 2 && (!row.isEmpty())) {
           //if you want the y coord of the row in the scene
           double y = ((TableRow)event.getSource()).getLocalToSceneTransform().getTy();
           int idx = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
           label.setText(idx 
               + " <-tbl row, idx in items-> "
               + items.indexOf(tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem())
               + ", first cell-> "
               + ((TableColumn)tableView.getColumns().get(0)).getCellData(idx));
       }
   });
   return row;
});
```

Comment: This doesn't return a TableCell node?

Comment: I thought you just wanted the information.  You can't easily get the TableCell as they continually get recycled.  You could put an onclick filter for each cell in a custom cell factory.  Better to ask why you need the cell and not the information contained.

Comment: I use ControlsFX PopOver, and it takes a node as a parameter. I want the PopOver to show over the row the user clicked on. @brian

Comment: I doubt you can re-use the cell.  Better to create a new node like a VBox and populate with labels from the row item.

Comment: you ain't reusing the cell, it just take the nodes location on the screen and places the box there @brian.

Comment: So you just want the screen coordinates of the cell or row?  I asked a question like that and it's complicated. http://stackoverflow.com/a/23420064/2855515

Comment: I added a snip of code to get the y-coord of the TableRow.

Comment: Thank you, that helped me to get to the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was to use the row as the Node and also turn the arrow location

```java
popup.setArrowLocation(PopOver.ArrowLocation.BOTTOM_CENTER);
```

This way, the popup shows up right over the TableRow